# How to set transparent background color in UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, uiimageview

I want to know how to set **Transparent background Color** in iOS. I have searched everywhere but I can't find anything. I want to set transparent background color like this:

[image]

Comment: hi you have done half  Transparent background if not then tell me so i can help you ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `opaque` to `NO` and `alpha` to 0.3, like this:

```
UIImageView *myImageView = ...
myImageView.opaque = NO;
myImageView.alpha = 0.3;
```

Comment: Thanks It's working..but how can i set this background color in half of imageview not fully in imageview area

Comment: @viratpuar Transparency/opacity is the property of the entire `UIView`, it cannot be set on a half of it. In order to set half of an image to transparent while keeping the other half opaque you could make two separate image views next to each other, set their opacity/alpha as you need, load the same image, and choose image positions within views to show adjacent parts as if they were a single image. [You would likely need to work with `CALayer` in order to accomplish this last item](http://stackoverflow.com/a/711210/335858).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight just to let you know you're missing a `*` somewhere ;)

Comment: @originaluser2 Thanks! That's a perfect case for suggesting an edit - it would be approved in no time at all!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight ah well it won't allow me to edit unless it's something over 6 chars

Answer (score 1):

try this one it will works :-

```
Your_ImageView.opaque = NO;

Your_ImageView.alpha = 0.3;
```